# how do we use media wiki format to edit email templates

Tags: grails, mediawiki, html-email

I have a few email templates currently in html format. I want to use mediawiki format. but it shows up as it is. also some parsers are to be set true for including images. where do we set that? I am using grails 1.3.7

Answer (score 0):

Grails does not natively support this. You will need to use a third party library to parse the media wiki into html. Take a look at the following list of media wiki parsers, hopefully one of the Java ones will meet your needs.